# Pie chart workbook

Tags: pie-chart, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have this query

```
AppInventory_CL
| where AppName_s in ('Adobe Acrobat DC (64-bit)') or AppName_s in ('Adobe Acrobat Reader - Italiano')
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s
| extend AppVersion_s_Dyn = split(AppVersion_s, '.')
| extend Versione = iif(toint(AppVersion_s_Dyn[0]) >= 23 and toint(AppVersion_s_Dyn[-1]) > 0 and AppName_s == 'Adobe Acrobat Reader - Italiano' or toint(AppVersion_s_Dyn[0]) >= 22 and AppName_s == 'Adobe Acrobat DC (64-bit)','OK','KO')
| summarize count() by Versione 
| render piechart
```

But in the pie chart I have wrong numbers (too many)
Any help?
Thanks

I need the correct number in the pie

Comment: your query appears to be missing the beginning of it, wehre the table names, etc are. and you haven't shown us what you are seeing, so we don't know exactly you mean "wrong numbers"

Comment: (though i guessed AppInventory_CL based on your other question)

Answer (score 0):

Step 0: look at your data in a grid view.

The pie chart is going to try to create one slice of pie for every row in that grid (though it might sum together items with the same text value)

if you are getting rows you don't expect, you'd need to further edit your query to get the right grid rows first, *then* display it as a bar chart once it has the right info

by my quick math, you'd get 2 rows always, `OK` and `KO`, and each of those would have the number of rows in that table after your first summarization, split into one or the other.

so you might need to look at if *that* part of the query is doing what you expect.

given that you summarize on `ManagedDeviceID_g` but then never reference it again... did you really mean:

> | summarize dcount(ManagedDeviceID_g) by Versione

to summarize the distinct number of devices in each bin, not the total number of rows?